# Calculate service hours between two DateTime objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I calculate number of hours/minutes between two `DateTime` objects, excluding off service hours.

For example I want to calculate number of service hours between `2017-09-13 17:50` and `2017-09-15 10:30`, while service hours are `09:00` to `18:00` daily.

I would love to find some efficient solution for this.

Comment: Are you look at a lib/gem or something like this?

Comment: I am not sure if some gem can provide this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested on this [working_hours](https://github.com/Intrepidd/working_hours) gem

```
require 'working_hours'

WorkingHours::Config.with_config(
  working_hours: {
    mon: {'09:00' => '18:00'},
    tue: {'09:00' => '18:00'},
    wed: {'09:00' => '18:00'},
    thu: {'09:00' => '18:00'},
    fri: {'09:00' => '18:00'},
    sat: {'09:00' => '18:00'},
    sun: {'09:00' => '18:00'},
  }
) do
  from = Time.parse('2017-09-13 17:50')
  to = Time.parse('2017-09-15 10:30')

  # in "seconds"
  service_hours = from.working_time_until(to)
end
```

Comment: Thanks mate. You saved my day :)

Comment: @RamizRaja Cool. No problem! :)